# How to get DOWNLOAD application time stamp from google play for android apps? Possible?

Tags: android

Is there any way we can get DOWNLOAD time stamp from Google Play Store for when application was downloaded ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to get [PackageInfo.firstInstallTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime)